# How to update an object of json in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a `json` file containing an array with some objects called `json.bc` shown by `fetch()` request.In every Item there is a a function called  `renderTotal`. The value of `<span className="Total-Price"></span>` is going to be called by `renderTotal`.There is a button by onclick function in render :

```
 <button onClick={((e)=>this.ChangePrice(e,this.renderChangePrice(element)))}>Select</button>
```

The value of `renderTotal` is going to be changed by `ChangePrice` function.let's debug what is going in `renderTotal`:

```
    renderTotal(element, NewAmount) {
    let Total = element.total
      if (NewAmount == '') {
        return new Intl.NumberFormat().format(Total)
    } else {
        return Total + NewAmount 
    }

}
```

The output of `renderTotal` depends on `NewAmount`,by default `NewAmount` is null and according to code if `NewAmount` is null The output of `renderTotal` will be `element.total`, but by running `ChangePrice` function `NewAmount` is not null :

```
    renderChangePrice(element){
    return 1000
   }
  ChangePrice = (e,elem) =>
  this.setState(
     {
         NewAmount: elem
     },
     () => {
     this.reorganiseLibrary();
     }
 )
```

For example by running `ChangePrice`, `NewAmount` will be 1000 and according to condition in `renderTotal` , the output of `renderTotal` will be `Total + NewAmount`.For instance the output of `renderTotal` is :

```
1000,5000,2000
```

by running `ChangePrice` it will be :

```
2000,6000,3000
```

Up to know every thing is fine but when I want to run `ChangePrice`for the second time I want the result be like this :

```
3000,7000,4000
```

I mean the `NewAmount` be added to last output of `renderTotal` not the default output of `renderTotal`,But I get again :

```
2000,6000,3000
```

And every time by running `ChangePrice` the output of `renderTotal` will be `NewAmount` + last output of `renderTotal`. How can I do it?

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        library: null,
        NewAmount: "",
    }

}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/json.bc', {
        method: 'POST',
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            const Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
            this.setState(state => ({
                ...state,
                data: Maindata
            }), () => {
                this.reorganiseLibrary()
                         })
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))
   }
    reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    let library = data;
    library = _.chunk(library);
    this.setState({library})
   }
   handlePerPage = evt => {
    this.setState({
        perPage: evt.target.value
    }, () => this.reorganiseLibrary());

}
  // handle render of library
   renderLibrary = () => {
    const { library } = this.state;
    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
        return <div className="nodata">No data</div>
    }
    return library.map((item, i) => (
        <div>
            <span className="Total-Price">{this.renderTotal(item, this.state.NewAmount)}</span>

        </div>

    ))
}

  render() {
    const { library } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
        {this.renderLibrary()}
        <button onClick={((e)=> this.ChangePrice(e,this.renderChangePrice(element)))}>Select</button>
        </div>
    )
}

renderTotal(element, NewAmount) {
    let Total = element.total
      if (NewAmount == '') {
        return new Intl.NumberFormat().format(Total)
    } else {
        return Total + NewAmount 
    }

}
renderChangePrice(element){
    return 1000
 }
 ChangePrice = (e,elem) =>
 this.setState(
     {
         NewAmount: elem
     },
     () => {
     this.reorganiseLibrary();
     }
 )
 }
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

**Edited:**

```
    renderTotal(element, NewAmount) {
    let Total = element.total
      if (NewAmount == '') {
        return new Intl.NumberFormat().format(Total)
    } else {
        let SliceElementSign = NewAmount.slice(0,1)
        let SliceElementNumber = parseInt(NewAmount.substr(1))
        if (SliceElementSign=='+'){

        return Total+SliceElementNumber
    }else{
         return Total-SliceElementNumber
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see there are couple of issue in your code.

1. You are changing the `NewAmount` in state from `''` to `1000` and then it stays at `1000` forever. You are not updating the value to `1000, 2000, 3000...` likewise.
2. If you don't want to update the `NewAmount` value, at least you will have update `library` element's `Total` value to the latest.

Currently, every time `ChangePrice` is being called, it sets NewAmount to `1000` because `renderChangePrice` always returns `1000` and it gets added to old value of element `Total`.

Updating you ChangePrice logic as below could help.

```
ChangePrice = (e, elem) => {
    this.setState(
        {
            NewAmount: (this.state.NewAmount || 0) + elem
        },
        () => {
            this.reorganiseLibrary();
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ashish.`NewAmount` will going to be changed. I set `1000` for instance to show it should be added in `renderTotal` every time `ChangePrice` function is running.

Comment: Actully `NewAmount` is going to be something like this :a number by a sing `+` or `-` ,for instance `+1000` or `-2000` an as I mentioned it will be changed every time.So `renderTotal` will be something you can see in **Edit** part of my code.

Comment: And when I `console.log(SliceElementNumber)` , it will be always `0` and every time this part will be done : `Total-SliceElementNumber`

Comment: When `NewAmount` is a number without a sign there is no problem  but by `+` or `-` it does not work.

Comment: I guess it wont be an issue, you will have to return -1000 from renderChangePrice

Comment: But `if` condition in `renderTotal` wont work correctly. When I get `console.log()` in `if` and `else` it is right but number wont be calculate correctly

Comment: When it is going to just minus or just sum number every thing is correct but when it is going to both minus and sum numbers, the result is not correct